# mediaelement.js audio player size

Tags: html5-audio

the webpage http://mediaelementjs.com/#installation read "player options" for audio it states width and height on lines 11 and 13 this however does not do anything to the players width or height.

// width of audio player
audioWidth: 400,
// height of audio player
audioHeight: 30

is this a bug? I know I can change everything manually through css but as its listed as an option I am curious if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to those JS parameters, but there's at least some basic control using the `width="__"` and `height="__"` parameters directly applied to the `<audio>` tag:

`<audio src="audio-file.mp3" width="100%" height="30px" controls="controls"></audio>`

The author of MediaElement.js uses those parameters when rendering the [responsive player](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/blob/master/demo/mediaelementplayer-responsive.html), for example.